# How can I add padding bottom after the x-axis label using apexchart

Tags: reactjs

I am having this Apex chart in my react app [image: Chart Image],

What I want to do is add more space between the x-axis label which is the month labels and the series name below it (Session Duration, Page Views, Total Visits). How can I achieve that

This is my code below

............................................................................................................................

```
 class ApexChart extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
          
            series: [{
                name: "Session Duration",
                data: [45, 52, 38, 24, 33, 26, 21, 20, 6, 8, 15, 10]
              },
              {
                name: "Page Views",
                data: [35, 41, 62, 42, 13, 18, 29, 37, 36, 51, 32, 35]
              },
              {
                name: 'Total Visits',
                data: [87, 57, 74, 99, 75, 38, 62, 47, 82, 56, 45, 47]
              }
            ],
            options: {
              chart: {
                height: 350,
                type: 'line',
                zoom: {
                  enabled: false
                },
              },
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              stroke: {
                width: [5, 7, 5],
                curve: 'straight',
                dashArray: [0, 8, 5]
              },
              title: {
                text: 'Page Statistics',
                align: 'left'
              },
              legend: {
                tooltipHoverFormatter: function(val, opts) {
                  return val + ' - ' + opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex][opts.dataPointIndex] + ''
                }
              },
              markers: {
                size: 0,
                hover: {
                  sizeOffset: 6
                }
              },
              xaxis: {
                categories: ['01 Jan', '02 Jan', '03 Jan', '04 Jan', '05 Jan', '06 Jan', '07 Jan', '08 Jan', '09 Jan',
                  '10 Jan', '11 Jan', '12 Jan'
                ],
              },
              tooltip: {
                y: [
                  {
                    title: {
                      formatter: function (val) {
                        return val + " (mins)"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    title: {
                      formatter: function (val) {
                        return val + " per session"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    title: {
                      formatter: function (val) {
                        return val;
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              grid: {
                borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
              }
            },
          
          
          };
        }

      

        render() {
          return (
            

      <div id="chart">
  <ReactApexChart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="line" height={350} />
</div>
    

          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some fiddling around with the Appchart demo, found 2 options that seem to provide result here.
Both use the **legend** key inside **options**, which you have in your code

1. You can add specific height to the legend container

   legend: {
   height: 100
   }
2. This will allow you to add margin to each legend.

legend: {
itemMargin: {
horizontal: 20
}
}

Hopefully someone with more experience with AppChart can provide a better solution but till then you can look into these.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Your solution was what I was looking for. I am very grateful for your help